# Mockito : given an instance of Class return the same instance

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I m trying to use mockito to mock a service. However I m not finding a way to say to mockito that given an instance of a class return me the same instance :

Something like :

```
  given(service.add(any(Individual.class)).willReturn(any(Individual.class));
```

any Idea how may I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can analyze invocation to access argument.

```
    given(service.add(any(Individual.class)))
            .will(invocation -> invocation.getArgument(0));
```

Comment: it works for me as follow : 
when(service.add(any(Individual.class))).thenAnswer(invocation -> Optional.of(invocation.getArgument(0)));

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg()`:

```
when(service.add(any(Individual.class)).then(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());
```

or with the BDD wrapper :

```
given(service.add(any(Individual.class)).willReturn(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());
```

Comment: Since my return is an Optional then I was not be able to do Optional.of(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg()) ... if not the answer is good

Comment: it works for me as follow : 
when(service.add(any(Individual.class)).thenAnswer(invocation -> Optional.of(invocation.getArgument(0)));

Comment: In fact you don't want to return the same object. You want to wrap it in an Optional. So yes your way of doing suits better.